# An alternative to nested loops in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, out-of-memory

I wanted to create a simple to calculate combinatorics.

```
var chars = new char[]{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
saveVariation(chars, 4);

public static void saveVariation(char characters[], int number_of_characters) {
    PrintWriter writer = null;
    try {
        writer = new PrintWriter(new File("variation.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

    }
    var length = characters.length;

    switch (number_of_characters) {
        case 2 -> {
            for (var i = 0; i < length; i += 1) {
                for (var j = 0; j < length; j += 1) {
                    writer.println(String.valueOf(characters[i]) + String.valueOf(characters[j]));
                }
            }
        }
        case 3 -> {
            for (var i = 0; i < length; i += 1) {
                for (var j = 0; j < length; j += 1) {
                    for (var k = 0; k < length; k += 1) {
                        writer.println(String.valueOf(characters[i]) + String.valueOf(characters[j]) + String.valueOf(characters[k]));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        case 4 -> {
            for (var i = 0; i < length; i += 1) {
                for (var j = 0; j < length; j += 1) {
                    for (var k = 0; k < length; k += 1) {
                        for (var l = 0; l < length; l += 1) {
                            writer.println(String.valueOf(characters[i]) + String.valueOf(characters[j]) + String.valueOf(characters[k]) + String.valueOf(characters[l]));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    writer.close();
}
```

As mentioned, nested loops can be replaced with recursion, but there is one major problem.

With a huge number of variations, there would be a memory overflow even after increasing it (more [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/821-0449/inst_increase_heap_size_t/#:%7E:text=Use%20the%20netbeans.,GB%20of%20RAM%3A%20512%20MB)), so I just save it to a file **variation.txt**.

So I need to modify the recursion to save to a file (I don't know exactly how). Also, I don't even know how to work with the file exactly. The code in the question works, but it's totally complicated.

Please help

Comment: Would you settle for not as *many* nested loops?

Comment: It might help if you were, before the code, describe what the code is supposed to do. (From reading the code, I think I know what it is supposed to do. But, you should tell us anyway.)

Comment: Recursion may help you

Comment: By the way, the `char` type is essentially broken, physically incapable of representing most characters. Likewise, `String#length`. Use Unicode code point integer numbers instead.

Comment: @BasilBourque have I told you how much I appreciate you trying to get people to do Unicode right? :) Thank you.

Comment: Does the order of characters matter, or do you just need each combination?

Comment: @user85421 Sorry, I modified the code in the question to save the variations to a file. But as I wrote, I don't know how to adjust it for recursion and how best to work with the file.

Comment: Don’t use this legacy syntax `char characters[]`. The idiomatic way to declare an array is `char[] characters`. Just follow the “type name” pattern, as with every variable.

Comment: Further note that you can use `characters.length` to get the length of the array. There is no need to pass the length in another parameter. This is Java, not C.

Answer (score 0):

```
var chars = new char[] {'a', 'b', 'c'};
int variations = 3;
    
var length = chars.length;
var list = new ArrayList<String>();
StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < variations; i++) out.append(chars[0]);

top:
while (true) {
  list.add(out.toString());
  for (int pos = variations - 1; pos >= 0; pos--) {
    char c = out.charAt(pos);
    int cPos = Arrays.binarySearch(chars, c);
    if (cPos < length -1) {
      // We can just increment this one and we're done
      out.setCharAt(pos, chars[cPos + 1]);
      continue top;
    } else {
      // 9-> 10: Every 'lower' digit is reset to first (0).
      out.setCharAt(pos, chars[0]);
    }
  }
  break;
}

System.out.println(list);
```

prints:

```
[aaa, aab, aac, aba, abb, abc, aca, acb, acc,
 baa, bab, bac, bba, bbb, bbc, bca, bcb, bcc,
 caa, cab, cac, cba, cbb, cbc, cca, ccb, ccc]
```

The way this works is to consider that, conceptually, what you want is **identical** to how the arabic numeric system works. i.e. how we count. What is the sequence of '0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...., 998, 999' other than exactly what you're doing here?

Thus, the algorithm is clear:

- To start we begin at the beginning: `00000` in numbers, or, in this system, `aaaaaa` - the first character on every position. We call this 'the current value'.
- We then add the current value and then replace the current value with its increment.
- To increment 'current value', we take the right-most character in it and replace it with the next character. This works.. until the right-most character has the same value as the last character in our set of chars. Then, just like '99' becomes '100', we instead set this right-most character back down to the *first* character in the set, and we aren't done incrementing yet - we now need to increment the next-to-right-most character. That one too could be at the final 'digit' (9 in numbers, 'c' in the code snippet), in which case, it, too, must be reset to 'a' and we need to continue our incrementing algorithm.
- If this incrementing algorithm gets through the entire string, we just break as that means we're done: The only way we can go through the whole thing if is the string is ccccccc - every position has the final digit.

NB: I use binarySearch to find the index of the 'char', this only works if `chars` is sorted. If it isn't, you'll have to write a quick little 'find index' method, or alternatively (if `chars` is very large, as in, over 500 or so characters, **and** isn't sorted, then looking through it every time is slow, **only then** go for this alternative): Instead of building characters in a StringBuilder, build up an array containing indices, not values. Now there is no need to look up where in the `chars` array the digit 'b' shows up. Then the code to add to the list (which here is just `list.add(out.toString())` becomes much more complicated, but on the whole this would be algorithmically an order of magnitude or two faster.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't want to write duplicate comments here about the error when using recursion (which I also wrote in the question) and that is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Comment: ITE is a wrapper exception thrown by reflective code. Absolutely nothing in your question can possibly throw it. Some framework runs your code and throws it evidently. It contains a stack trace of what exception caused the ITE and _that_ is the relevant one. Scroll down until it says 'caused by' - that's the one you want to be looking at.

Comment: Sorry, I take back my last answer. I don't want to write duplicate answers here, but this can be solved by saving to a file, but I don't know how to modify your code to do this? Can you do it please?

Comment: There’s no need to worry about large arrays here, due to the exponential number of possible combinations they are impossible to process anyway. But you can do without the search by taking the number analogy a step further. To iterate over all combinations, just iterate from zero to nⁿ. To write or print a combination, use an idiomatic “format number to baseₙ string” approach, just using the character array for the digit symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Picking up the idea of Diego Borba you could implement it as follows. Please note that the following code is untested:

```
String[] array = new String[]{"a", "b", "c", "d"};

public static List<String> create(int maxLength, String[] array){
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    strings.addAll(create("",0, maxLength, array));
    return strings;
}

private static List<String> create(String current, int currentLength, int maxLength, String[] array){
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    if(currentLength < maxLength){
        for(int x=0;x<array.length;x++){
           strings.addAll(create(current + array[x],currentLength + 1, maxLength, array));
        }
    }else{
        strings.add(current);
    }
    return strings;
}
```

The code adds a single character to the empty start String for each of the letters a,b,c and d. Then it adds the next a,b,c or d to the already created string a,b,c and d and so.

If the current length of the string is smaller than the expected length, then it keeps adding a character. Otherwise it stops and returns the list. The last step is to add all the created Strings to the List of Strings and return it as a result.

Comment: You'll need the type on `String current` in the parameter list of the three-argument `create`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, missed it as I wrote it down without testing.

Comment: @TobiasHorst Thank you, but as I already wrote in the question, it still crashes with the error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError, which I don't know how to deal with.

Comment: @MichalRama I don't think that the different code snippets are the problem. How many characters do you pass into the method? java.lang.OutOfMemoryError occurs only when the JVM cannot use more memory. I think the amount of objects (in other words number of character combinations)  that get created an in turn the allocated memory is too large as you already wrote in the question. I think you can just allocate more heap space as all created String objects are needed and the JVM cannot remove them by garbage collection.

Comment: @TobiasHorst Just for example, I wrote an array of 38 elements. Here, the length of 5 characters is enough for such a large number of variations that the program crashes. I tried using the instructions (given in the link in the question) to increase the memory of NetBeans itself to 6GB and it still didn't help, although it takes a while before it crashes (before it did it immediately). Can it be solved somehow, please? Actually I couldn't even figure out how big the field is when the error occurs.

Comment: You are creating too much elements. That's the gap between theory and practice. A lot of things are computable in theory but in practice you have limited resources to compute such things. This is also the case here.

Comment: @TobiasHorst Yes, I know there are clear limits (despite the performance of today's computers), but is it solvable or not? Like I said, I wanted to put it in multiple arrays if it doesn't fit in one array capacitively.

Comment: It is solveable when you give the JVM the amount of memory that is required to store the computation or you find a solution to compute the results partially one by one. Storing the results multiple arrays will not solve your problem.

Comment: @TobiasHorst You are right, using two arrays is nonsense. But, now I thought of another solution - not to save in an array, but in a file. There is no risk of memory overflow. However, I don't know how to modify your code to do this. Can you do it please?

Comment: @MichalRama even if you would only need one nanosecond per combination, processing all combinations of 38 elements will take longer than the current age of the universe. And there’s no way to store them, not in memory and not in a file. On the other hand, neither your original code nor this answer’s code will have any problems with five characters. If that doesn’t work, there’s a fundamental problem with your environment, entirely unrelated to this task.

Answer (score 0):

As Diego Borba pointed out, recursion is helpful here.

```
// add the next character to the string, or the string to the list
public void variations(List<String> list, int remaining, String soFar, int... codePoints) {
    if (remaining == 0) {
        list.add(soFar);
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < codePoints.length; ++i) {
            variations(list, remaining - 1,
                soFar + Character.toString(codePoints[i]), codePoints);
        }
    }
}

// recursively generate all possible combinations
public List<String> getVariation(int number, int... codePoints) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    variations(list, number, "", codePoints);
    return list;
}
```

Call it with `getVariation(3, "abc".codePoints().toArray())` and it will return:

```
[aaa, aab, aac, aba, abb, abc, aca, acb, acc,
 baa, bab, bac, bba, bbb, bbc, bca, bcb, bcc,
 caa, cab, cac, cba, cbb, cbc, cca, ccb, ccc]
```

As Basil Bourque pointed out, it is better to use integer code points than `char`, which is why I am calling it with `"abc".codePoints().toArray()` but you can also call it like `getVariation(4, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd')` if you prefer.

If you would rather send the output to a file, use this:

```
// add the next character to the string, or write the string to the file
public void variations(PrintWriter writer, int remaining, String soFar, int... codePoints) {
    if (remaining == 0) {
        writer.println(soFar);
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < codePoints.length; ++i) {
            variations(writer, remaining - 1,
                soFar + Character.toString(codePoints[i]), codePoints);
        }
    }
}

// recursively generate all possible combinations
public void getVariation(String filename, int number, int... codePoints) throws IOException {
    try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(filename)), UTF_8)) {
        variations(writer, number, "", codePoints);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your code works. I really like writing those characters in one string. But as I wrote in the question, if the amount is too large, it crashes with a java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException error. Plus there's the problem of how to store combinations in multiple fields if they exceed its maximum limit.

Comment: @MichalRama What parameters are you calling it with? How big a list of combinations are you trying to generate? And at what line is the exception thrown? I can't see how InvocationTargetException could be thrown by any of the code in your question or any of the answers.

Comment: Sorry, I take it back. The InvocationTargetException was caused by the OpenJavaFX library, which I don't need in this case. After removing it, the error disappeared.

However, as I already wrote in the question, it still crashes with java.lang.OutOfMemoryError, which I don't know how to deal with.

Comment: @MichalRama You've never stated how many different letters there are or how many are in each variation. Obviously at some point the number of variations could be larger than the memory in your computer, or even larger than the number of atoms in the universe.

Comment: I just wanted to be able to create an array that would contain the specified number of variations. And if the array capacity is insufficient, it will store it in more arrays. I honestly didn't set any limits, but I definitely didn't want to create anything in the trillions.

Comment: @MichalRama but what are the parameters you are passing in? Why won't you say? Do you understand that, depending on the parameters, it may be more than can be held in memory at all? What parameters do you call it with?

Comment: Sorry, I take back my last answer. I don't have a fixed limit, but as I already wrote in the question itself, it can be solved by saving to a file. There is no risk of memory overflow. But I don't know exactly how to modify your code to do that as well. Can you do it please?

Comment: @MichalRama So what if you don't have a fixed limit? That's completely beside the point. The number of variations is `n^p` where n is the number of characters and p is the number in each variation. Why won't you just state what parameters you call it with, or at least what the numbers are? How many letters? How many in each variation? If you save it to a file there's no possibility of memory overflow, but it will overflow your disk unless it's infinite. Anyway, I've rewritten it to save to a file.

Comment: It's wild that you just flat out refuse to say what parameters you call it with. 26 different letters, 100 at a time, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a loop to *iterate* over (or *simulate*) the inner loops and an array to hold the indices of this inner loops:

```
static void saveVariation(BufferedWriter output, int count, int... characters) throws IOException {
    var index = new int[count];
    var length = characters.length;
    while (true) {
        // create and output one word using the indices in array
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            output.write(Character.toChars((characters[index[i]])));
        }
        output.newLine();

        // increment the index/indices (last to first)
        for (var i = count-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (++index[i] < length) {
                break;
            } else {
                index[i] = 0;
                if (i == 0) {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code is receiving an array (varargs) of `int` instead of `char` so it works with any Unicode code point, not only the first 65536 that can be represented by `char`.

The method can be called like

```
saveVariation(writer, 4, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
```

Should be easy to change the `int...` to `String...` for even more *complex* use cases.